# How to update multiple columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update multiple columns with a single query

This is my code: I want to update the `Employee` table and the table has multiple null values in `EmployeeCode` column that I have to update with new value.

```
update Employee 
set EmployeeCode = 26589, EmployeeCode = 26587 
where EmployeeID = 'EA45AED9-94A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C' 
  and EmployeeID = '0A362F00-96A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C';
```

Comment: Your code appears to be updating one column in two (or more) different rows.

Comment: Use two UPDATE statements.

Comment: Ok thanks !! it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to, you can do it in one step, using CTE:

```
WITH Pairs (code, id)
AS (
  SELECT 26589 AS code, 'EA45AED9-94A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C' AS id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 26587 AS code, '0A362F00-96A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C' AS id
)
UPDATE Employee set EmployeeID = Pairs.id
FROM Pairs
INNER JOIN Employee ON (pairs.code = Employee .EmployeeCode)
```

Explanation:

- the `WITH Pairs (...)  AS (...)` part defines the code - id pairs you need. You can use as many `SELECT` -s here, as you need. Just keep `UNION` -ing them.
- After the `WITH` you can update your `Employee` table. All you need to do is to do an `INNER JOIN` on your `Pairs` subquery. So you'll update only those rows that `you want to.

Comment: This is a complicated way but still, it does it in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Two separate updates is the simplest way:

```
update Employee
    set EmployeeCode = 26589
    where EmployeeID = 'EA45AED9-94A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C' ;

update Employee
    set EmployeeCode = 26587
    where EmployeeID = '0A362F00-96A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C';
```

You can wrap this in a transaction so they are effective at the same time.

You *can* merge them into one statement:

```
update Employee
    set EmployeeCode = (case when EmployeeID = 'EA45AED9-94A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C'26589 then 26589 else 26587 end)
    where EmployeeID in ('EA45AED9-94A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C', '0A362F00-96A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C');
```

But that seems unnecessary.

If you have more than two, then this might be recommended:

```
update e
    set EmployeeCode = v.EmployeeCode
    from Employee e join
         (values ('EA45AED9-94A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C', 26589),
                 ('0A362F00-96A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C', 26587)
         ) v(EmployeeId, EmployeeCode)
         on e.EmployeeId = v.EmployeeId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` statement

```
UPDATE Employee
SET    EmployeeCode = CASE EmployeeID
                        WHEN 'EA45AED9-94A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C' THEN 26589
                        ELSE 26587
                      END
WHERE  EmployeeID IN ( 'EA45AED9-94A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C', '0A362F00-96A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C' );
```

**Note :** I have assumed `'EA45AED9-94A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C'` maps to `26589` code, if not swap the values

Comment: @Amit - If you know basic sql then you should be able to handle it with another `when`

Comment: This is cool cool for relatively small datasets. Otherwise it's cumbersome to maintain the `EmployeeId`-s twice. Also, a large `CASE`-`WHEN` is a bit slower than absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Separate your SQL-statements

```
UPDATE Employee
SET EmployeeCode = 26589,
WHERE EmployeeID = 'EA45AED9-94A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C'
```

---

```
UPDATE Employee
SET EmployeeCode = 26587
WHERE EmployeeID = '0A362F00-96A6-E711-AF12-E4029B75E01C';
```